# My SQL query is taking too long, is there another approach?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to store 3D vector images in my MariaDB, but I'm finding that retrieving the data is taking far too long to be practical.

I have a few tables:

a points table containing the x,y and z coordinates plus the entity id,

an entity table containing a unique id, an entity type (text, line, polyline,etc) other common attributes such as colour and linetype,

and some auxiliary tables containing additional values like text, text height, line thicknesses and flags split into separate tables based on field type (varchar, int or float).

I am accessing the data through PHP as follows:

```php
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT entityID,X,Y,Z FROM dwgpoints WHERE drawing=".$DrawingID." AND blockID=".$blockID.";"))
{
  $previous_eID=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $eID=$row['entityID'];
    if($previous_eID!=$eID)
    {
      if($previous_eID)// confirm it's not zero
        renderEntity($image_handle,$DrawingID,$previous_eID,$etype,$colour,$ltype,$points, $transformation, $clip);
      $previous_eID=$eID;
      if($eResult=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT colour,ltype,etype FROM entity WHERE drawing=".$ID." AND eID=".$eID.";")){
        $erow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($eResult);
        $colour=$erow['colour'];
        $ltype=$erow['ltype'];
        $etype=$erow['etype'];
        $points=[[$row['X'],$row['Y'],$row['Z']]];
      }
    }else{
      $points[]=[$row['X'],$row['Y'],$row['Z']];
    }
  }
}
```

This process is taking up to ten minutes, but I know that Openstreetmaps, for example, renders tiles from similar amounts of data.

The results of the EXPLAIN directive is as follows:

```
MariaDB [wptest_11]> EXPLAIN SELECT entityID,X,Y,Z FROM dwgpoints WHERE drawing=2 AND blockID=-1;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | dwgpoints | ref  | idx_id        | idx_id | 9       | const,const | 24939 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Is it possible to streamline my data searches to make the process time manageable? I'm on a cheap VPS, so there may be hardware performance issues, in which case would an upgrade make much difference? Or do I need to rethink my approach?

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Why not store all of your points information in a single binary column?

Comment: Is the query what's slowing things down? Then post the output of `EXPLAIN <your_query>;`, the table structure and possibly `show indexes from dwgpoints;`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I deduce from them that query should be practical to implement. I'll edit the OP with the EXPLAIN data (Thanks for that).

Comment: Use a `JOIN` to get everything at once, instead of a nested loop with lots of `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I have run millions of records on a Raspberry Pi3 with better performance. Hardware helps, but I would first look at:

- Minimizing your calls, if it makes sense for your application
- Add some indexes on fields in your WHERE clause to improving performance

**Single Query**

Adjust the following query to fit your needs. Then see what the timing is. For 26k results, you should be well under a second.

```
SELECT 
    a.entityID
  , a.X
  , a.Y
  , a.Z 
  , b.colour
  , b.ltype
  , b.etype 
  , b.drawing
 FROM dwgpoints   a
 LEFT JOIN entity b 
 ON     b.eID     = a.entityID 
    AND b.drawing = a.drawing
 WHERE 
     a.drawing = ".$ID." 
 AND a.blockID = ".$blockID.
 ;
```

**Indexes**

Create some indexes:

1. The combination of `drawing` and `blockID` for the `dwgpoints` table.
2. The combination of `drawing` and `eID` for the `entity` table.

Re-run the above query, there should be an improvement.

I would also look at adding a foreign key between the tables, which will help improve data integrity of your database.